# Sending push notifications from Flutter application

Tags: dart, flutter

We need to send push notifications from our flutter app when certain actions take place. I have looked at Firebase and OneSignal, is there an easier way to accomplish this? Firebase seems difficult to set up and all the examples have you sending notifications from their admin console which is not what we want. I ran the OneSignal example app and it didnt work in my emulator when I sent a test message to myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally think Firebase is the way to go here. I personally use OneSignal, and they're great for what I want Push Notifications for. However, I don't really think OneSignal would work for you because you would like to use Push Notifications for something a lot more advanced. That's what Firebase is for.

Comment: So with fire base we can send them from the app when let’s say a button is clicked? I didn’t see that capability but I didn’t spend much time on it

Comment: Under the section __Sending Messages__ for the [FCM package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_messaging) you can see how you need to structure the message, which can then be created on a button click. Eventually you can fetch the required parameters before creating the DATA object necessary for the "curl command".

Comment: Ill give it a shot thanks for the direction, we are almost ready to launch so I didnt want to go down the wrong path.